# Java Method Overwrite Lists

Tags: java, interface

I have the following structure

```
public interface A <T extends B> {

  List<String> getVals();

  void setVals(List<String> vals);

  T getContext();

  void setContext(T context);
}

public abstract class C <T extends B> implements A {
   protected T context;

   //Some code
}

public class Regex <T extends B> extends C <T> {
   public List<String> getVals() {
     //Some code
   }

   public void setVals(List<String> vals) {
     //Some code
   }
}
```

The thing is that, when I compile, I'm getting the following error:

```
Regex.java:[53,15]
name clash: setVals(java.util.List<java.lang.String>) in Regex and setVals(java.util.List<java.lang.String>) in A have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
```

Why is this? If I ask Intellij to "do the overwrite" for me and it replaces the setVals(List vals) with setVals(List vals) instead.

```
   public void setVals(List vals) {
     //Some code
   }
```

It shouldn't be, "exactly the same definition of the method"?

Sorry in advance for my lack of interfaces knowledge

Comment: Your `C` extends the raw type `A` which will lead to all kinds of problems. Did you mean `C` to extend `A<T>` instead?

Comment: in other words: it should have been `public abstract class C<T extends B> implements A<T>` and not `implements A`

Comment: You all mentioned the same and, ofc, it was the correct approach. Now it fixed. Amazing!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [interface and a class. name clash: same erasure, yet neither overrides other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442508/interface-and-a-class-name-clash-same-erasure-yet-neither-overrides-other)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing you want to implement parameterized type but are actually implementing the raw one.

Replace

```
public abstract class C <T extends B> implements A
```

with

```
public abstract class C <T extends B> implements A<T>
```

An interesting observation to note here is, that the function `setVals` is not even using the type parameter `T`, even then there is a name clash. So it is not obvious at first why this is happening, and why simply extending, `A<T>` works. At least not to me.

The answer lies [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8),

> The supertype of a class may be a raw type. Member accesses for the
>   class are treated as normal, and member accesses for the supertype are
>   treated as for raw types. In the constructor of the class, calls to
>   super are treated as method calls on a raw type.

and

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type C that is not inherited from its
>   superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to
>   the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

`C` in our case is also coincidentally `C`.

So without extending `A<T>` from `C`s perspective the signature of A is,

```
void setVals(List vals)
```

and the compiler doesn't see `void setVals(List<String> vals)` in `Regex` as **overriding** that of A, instead it is considering it **overloading**, and that too an illegal overload because of type erasure. (You can't overload `foo(List)` with `foo(List<String>)`